# Sort group of columns based on the order of a certain column

Tags: excel, sorting, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

So, I have a Google sheets documents with some info.
AS you can see in the column c holds the correct order of the "old names". This old names are the same of column I, but in this case they are not correctly ordered. I want to sort column I,J,K, by the order of column c. I've tried to match the values of column I with column C, but i don't know how to make column J and K follow the order too.

[image: explanation]

Comment: You can not have merged cells when sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose other options for personalize your order.

[image: Sorting advance options]

In this picture you can see that first you should select all columns that you need order and in data tab select "Sort range - Advance sorting options".
This way, you can introduce diferent levels for sorting your data.